# Create worksheets with the date as the worksheet title - Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, date, openpyxl

Wondering if someone can help me out.  I'm new to Python and trying to get the below to add each date from a list to the new sheets created. How would I add the dates in the list to each worksheet?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Python/Excel/Roster.xlsx')

start="24-10-2021"    
last="02-01-2022"  
start_date=datetime.strptime(start,"%d-%m-%Y")  
last_date=datetime.strptime(last,"%d-%m-%Y")  
dates=[]  
while start_date <= (last_date - timedelta(days=7)):  
    start_date += timedelta(days=7)  
    dates.append(start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))


original_ws = wb.active

num_of_required_sheet_copies = 10

for n in range(num_of_required_sheet_copies):
    # Create a copy of the first worksheet
    ws = wb.copy_worksheet(original_ws)
    # Rename new worksheet
    
    for date in dates:
        ws.title = date

wb.save('C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Python/Excel/New.xlsx')
```

Comment: It's better to use datetime.date objects throughout rather than converting from strings.

Comment: I think the nested loop setting the titles would try to give the same name to each worksheet. Try `ws.title = dates[n]`